# Tesseract tesstrain.sh can not find the font

Tags: tesseract, tesstrain

I am trying to train tesseract with the guide of:
https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/TrainingTesseract-4.00.html

But even though i did not put a font argument in my command line i get this error:
Could not find font named 'Arial Bold'.
Pango suggested font 'Palatino'.
Please correct --font arg.
ERROR: Program text2image failed. Abort.

I couldn't find that where am i making the mistake?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acDRf.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

So i find the solution in:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/CpxTGGUlWIo

I listed fonts whose i want to train on them to get their names with:nour@nour:~$ text2image --fonts_dir path/to/fonts  --list_available_fonts

Then i edited the: language-specific.sh with the font names which i will train the tesseract on it.